# Isomorphism classes and invariant factors of abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group with $ord(G)=3374=2\cdot 7\cdot 241$. Calculate all isomorphism classes with the invariant factors $k_1\ ...k_n$ sucht that $k_i$ divides $k_j$ $(i<j)$.

Since $ord(G)=2\cdot 7\cdot 241$ it follows that $$G\cong \mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_7\oplus\mathbb Z_{241}$$ is the isomorphism class. But $2\ |\ 7\ |\ 241$ is false, so how can we determine the invariant factors $k_1,k_2,k_3$?

Comment: I think, my isomorphism class is wrong. It have to be $G\cong \mathbb Z_{2\cdot 7\cdot 241}$, because of the exponent partition, the number of isomorphism class is one.

Comment: The group $G$ is cyclic of order 3374. That is the only invariant factor.